# Using CSS Animations to keep element hidden for n seconds after page load

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

A few years back we added a note to our web page for users who are blocking JS. I would really like the note to stay hidden for folks who have JS on. The note's visibility relies on the body having a class `body class="noJS"`. In order to remove that as swiftly as possible I have a JS as the very first item in the body tag that does not rely on anything but fires right away.

```
<!-- BODY element exists! -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/ 
        document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(new RegExp(\'(?:^|\\s)\'+ \'no-js\' + \'(?:\\s|$)\'), \' \'); 
    /*]]>*/ 
</script>
```

In Firefox I still see the note as a red flickering, for example on the top of the main page here https://www.colorperfect.com

Annoying, which leads to my question can I use CSS3 animations to fade in that note say after a one second delay? That should fix it I guess but I have never done anything with CSS animations so I figured I'd ask rather than fiddle... If that does not work other ideas would be welcome, too.

**Edit:**

This is the CSS that produces the red block. A simple matter of exchaning background and height.

```
body.noJS .single_navi_zeile
{
  background-color:#BB0000;
  height:12.7em;
  background-position: left 0.5em bottom 0.3em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../grafik/nojs.png");
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Instead of your overly complicated regex solution, you can do `document.body.classList.remove("noJS");`. What you are asking for is `animation-delay: 3s;`.

Comment: @connexo https://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist I don't think so, won't break legacy IE support for this, thanks for the delay I was looking for.

Comment: Supporting IE 9 and below in 2019 is really not an option imo. And btw, those stone age "browsers" also don't support CSS animations.

Comment: @connexo You know I did not ask about that but to clarify enough of our customers use hardware that needs legacy OS versions, how they secure those is none of our business, but XP Support is mandatory and that means IE 8 even in 2020...

Comment: having delays and stuff is not a good solution and will cause to false positives on such old machines with i guess not that much computing power. try to build stable solutions like the one i mentioned in my answer. simply doesn't display the banner and only display it if the user is on `noJS`. That's it.

Comment: @Felix That is what I'm doing already but it flickers. It's a browser rendering thing really and whatever feat will render it differently is welcome.

Comment: just to get the first thing right: you apply 'no-js' but you css names it `noJS` ? what's correct here?

Comment: @Felix This is hillarious, always bet on stupidity... That was what I really needed, there is no 'no-js' class...

Comment: It's late in the evening ... :)

Comment: @Felix must have been late in the evening years ago as well, but it's still acting up in terms of flasing a red graphic it shouldn't. I'll see what happens on the live system tomorrow with the daily update to the code base and all caching mechanisms the test environment is slooow. If it persists I'll revive the question...

Comment: it's really strange. maybe some js dom manipulation? the concept of this is very easy: hide banner by default. if browser has no js, apply `no-js`. display banner based on `no-js` class. try to figure out which code is interferring and follow these 3 steps. should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should provide you the fade in effect you are after. Animation delays postpone  when an animation starts and so you might end up with the element appearing, then vanishing suddenly only to fade back in again.
If you begin the animation right away but start from `opacity: 0` and then after 1s (50% of a 2s duration) fade it back in you should get what you're after.

```css
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {opacity: 0}
  50% {opacity: 0}
  100% {opacity: 1}
}

.anim-fade-in {
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<p class="anim-fade-in">Some content</p>
```

Worth noting that the element is only hidden using opacity by this approach and so you may find that the page content moves as the element itself is present before being removed. You could experiment with sliding the element in instead.

Comment: I see you mention needing IE8 support. Unfortunately my suggestion here wouldn't help there as support for CSS animations doesn't come along until IE10.

Comment: Don't worry about the legacy IEs, they just need to work and they'd just not animate. Still I could not make it work out as I was dealing with a change in background color, height and opacity and I made a mess of it somehow. Upvoted yours as it points in the direction I asked.

Comment: At the end of the day I used the code you pointed me to but needed an `animation: fade-in 1s normal forwards;` to make things stay what they were at the end of the animation, otherwise it all jumped reverted to the initial state...

Answer (score 1):

did you try css for that?

```css
.redBanner {
  display: none;
}
body.no-js .redBanner {
  display: block;
}
```

or with your example

```css
body.no-js .single_navi_zeile {
  background-color:#BB0000;
  height:12.7em;
  background-position: left 0.5em bottom 0.3em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../grafik/nojs.png");
}
```

Comment: Yes basically, I'm not switching between display none and block but in one case there is a background graphic and in the other not. I'll edit it into the question.

Comment: I'm accepting this because of your comment that solved my actaul predicament from way back when and made the whole animation business obsolete for this. Thank you.